Assembly addition program
i have the following code
section .bss
    num1 resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    res1 resb 2
    res2 resb 2

section .data
    fir dw 'Ingrese el primer numero: '
    lfir equ $ - fir
    sec dw 'Ingrese el segundo numero: '
    lsec equ $ - sec

    newline db 10


section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov dl,lfir     ;print "Ingrese el primer numero: "
    mov ecx,fir
    mov bl,1
    mov al,4
    int 0x80

    mov dl,5        ;read the first number
    mov ecx,num1
    mov bl,2
    mov al,3
    int 0x80

    mov dl,lsec     ;print "Ingrese el segundo numero: "
    mov ecx,sec
    mov bl,1
    mov al,4
    int 0x80

    mov dl,5        ;read the second number
    mov ecx,num2
    mov bl,2
    mov al,3
    int 0x80

    mov eax,[num1]  ;move the first number into eax
    mov ebx,[num2]  ;move the second number to ebx
    sub ebx,48      ;conver the number to decimal
    add eax,ebx     ;add the 2 numbers
    mov [res1],eax  ;move the result into "res1"

    cmp eax, 57 ;check if the result has 2 digits
    jle singledigit ;instructions when it has 2 digits

    mov eax,[res1]
    sub eax,10
    mov [res1],eax
    mov ebx,'1'
    mov [res2],ebx

    mov dl,2        ;print res2
    mov ecx,res2
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80

    mov dl,2        ;print res1
    mov ecx,res1
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80

    jmp finish

singledigit:
    mov dl,2        ;print res1
    mov ecx,res1
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80

    jmp finish

finish:
    mov dl,1        ;new line
    mov ecx,newline
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80

    mov al,1
    int 0x80

It seems like it will always ignore the singledigit label, and therefore prints ascii characters below 48 (ascii 0) when the sum is less than 10, but it works fine when the sum is greater than 10

mov eax,[num1] reading 4 bytes from a 2-byte variable seems like a bad idea. Maybe you should use something like movzx eax, byte [num1] (and similarly for num2).

Hey, i was wondering if you knew how data is stored when given 2 digits, for example 12? Will it save as 50 and 49 on 2 different bytes, or will it add and store as 99 on a single byte? And if it is stored in 2 different bytes, which one is stored on num1 and which on num1 + 1

@Fotatata "how data is stored when given 2 digits"? In this case you're working with assembly. A byte can store values 0-255. For values larger than that you'll need multiple bytes. Each general purpose x86 register you're using (eax, ebx, ecx, etc) stores 4 bytes. For your example, the number 12 is only two digits in a base-10 system. In binary it is 00001100 and in hex it is 0xc. As you can see, this number easily fits within a byte (8 bits) and will therefore easily fit within a general purpose x86 register.

@h0r53 well i meant as input, when the user input is 12, since its 2 ascii characters (49 for 1 and 50 for 2) i was wondering how it is stored, since i store the user's input on num1 and num2

It's going to store the value of the ascii characters one at a time, based on the system call used and the surrounding assembly. It looks like you're using the system call for read to read a single character at a time. You're storing the result of read in the reserved byte num1. You never read the second digit from the input stream.

Just like Michael said, replacing every
mov eax,[num1] with

movzx eax,byte [num1]; 

and the same for ebx and num2, did solve the issue
